# List Views are not shown in the menus

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, view, hidden

I have a list with some views defined. In the SharePoint designer where all files are listed I can find all:

[image]

Taking a look into the SharePoint UI there are listed only a few:

[image]
[image]

And also in the "Views" View of the SharePoint disigner there are not listed all:

[image]

However, typing the url of the views listed in the first picture work.

**Why are some views not listed in the UI? Is there a setting to show/hide them or is it a sort of bug?**

Edit:
I found [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-c222a75d-8b18-44e2-9ed8-7ee4e0d23cfc) article which describes to hide views from the ribbon. In my case the two views are neither visible in the box to hide/show them, so I guess there is a problem somewhere:

[image]

Edit:
Here the screenshot about Views and Forms:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On first image You have views to forms, not for lists. What do You want to do? Create new view to form or new view to list?

Comment: No, there are listed ALL forms and views of that list. If in the SharePoint Designer you navigate into `AllFiles`-> `Lists`->yourList you will find all forms and views. In the UI `MyItems` and `MeineAbteilung` are missing.

Comment: Downvote because you are not supplying an answer to the question. For statement like this use comments instead.

Comment: @Emaborsa and Your comment add something useful...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, the “Ema” is a personal view. The personal views will not display in “Views” in SharePoint Designer. Only public views will list in the “Views”. So that, you can only find “Alle Anfragen” and “Meine Offenen” in the “Views”.

And I think “MeineAbteilung” and “MyItems” are not list views. They are just pages (ASPX files). You can open “MeineAbteilung.aspx” and “MyItems.aspx”, compare them with “MeineOffenen.aspx” and “AllItems.aspx” to see if they are ASPX files rather than list views. If so, they will not be listed in “Views” and in UI because they are not list views.

Comment: No, `MeineAbteilung` and `MyItems` are `Views`. However, I added a screenshot about views and forms. There you can see they are missing.